# Is it safe to use a proxy? Can it steal my bandwidth or ip?

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, ip-address

When it comes to using a proxy for one of my applications, I am unsure about the safety that comes with it. Can a proxy steal my bandwidth or my ip address if it is being used for only one application? I don't care for the privacy aspect of it as I only care to mask my ip. Is there other ways to mask my ip in an application (i.e. browsers) without risking my bandwidth or ip? Is a proxy even a threat in that regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stealing your IP isn't a thing. It can't be stolen, but it can be revealed to the very people you're trying to hide it from. If you're trying to hide it from law enforcement, you should be very worried about that.

Stealing your bandwidth is possible if malware is installed on your machine, which is possible if you're using a proxy run by criminals. But that's not the threat you should be worried about. You should be worried about them stealing everything else. Personal identity information, passwords, credit card numbers, banking info, etc. -- all these things can potentially be compromised by using a proxy. And if you're using it for activity that's illegal in your country, you should be very worried that the proxy is run by law enforcement.

As Marc.2377 pointed out in his answer, a VPN is a much safer solution.

Comment: The purpose for me using a proxy is in no way illegal, which is why I don't have a problem with it. I was just worried for security of my ip and bandwidth, so as long as that's not the problem, nothing else should affect me. (Since I am not logging into or buying anything)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer but you should slow down on accepting answers. You accepted Marc.2377's answer in less than an hour and then switched to mine a few minutes later. Please don't do that. Let your question sit for at least a day or two before accepting an answer. An upvote is a more appropriate response this early (and when you finally do accept an answer, you should also upvote it).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, an [HTTP proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) will talk to external web servers on behalf of your computer, and obviously talk to your computer as well. But it should not be able to request any resources (external or otherwise) *through* your computer, though. For that to happen, your computer must be acting as a proxy server.

Of course, depending on the particular proxy client you are using, this might be a possibility. [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/), for instance, may redirect requests from other machines through your PC (with the possibility, upon opt-in, to act as an *exit node* as well), although in this mode the software is also operating as a router (hence, *The Onion Router*) and not only as a simple proxy client. <sup>[1]</sup>

That said, there are other risks inherent to using proxy software to browse the web. See for instance [this article](https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-risks).

<sub>[1]: https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/</sub>